# nginx cache prematurely emptying

Tags: nginx

We have a legacy application that is fairly wobbly and until the people responsible can make it behave better I'm trying to improve its reliability by sticking up an nginx cache in front of it. Unfortunately this application also does some redirecting for downloads based on useragent which makes caching this a total pain.

So the two objectives of this are:

1. Serve stale static content and update in the background to make it faster. And if the event the origin goes down serve static content.
2. In the event the origin goes down perform a generic redirect to the windows downloads page. From there the users should be able to navigate to other OS pages that are in cache.

However despite the 10gb cache size and a 30Gb disk it never seems to build more than 20-30mb of cache.
[image: nginx plus cache zones]

[image: nginx dashboard]

I can hit a page and `X-Cached MISS` will be returned, hit it again and get `X-Cached HIT`, then randomly it will go back to `X-Cached MISS` again and not `STALE` or `UPDATING` as I would expect.

Permissions seem correct. I even tried deleting the directory to allow nginx to recreate it.

```
drwx------  18 nginx root  4096 Apr 17 22:10 nginx-cache
```

File size on disk is tiny

```
sudo du -hs nginx-cache/
27M     nginx-cache/
```

No shortage of space either

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            818M     0  818M   0% /dev
tmpfs           166M   18M  149M  11% /run
/dev/sda1        30G  3.5G   26G  12% /
tmpfs           828M     0  828M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           828M     0  828M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           166M     0  166M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Config below.

```
proxy_cache_path /nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m max_size=10g use_temp_path=off;

map $query_string $has_os {
    "~.*os=.*" 1;
}


server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;

    location @downloads-redirect {
        add_header X-Nginx-Redirect true;
        rewrite ^.* $1?os=win10x64 redirect;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_cache STATIC;
        proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
        proxy_cache_lock on;
        proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Vary Set-Cookie Expires;
        proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
        proxy_cache_valid 200 5m;
        proxy_cache_background_update on;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;
        proxy_pass http://foo.bar.com;

        location ~* "downloads/[a-z]{4}.html$" {
            proxy_intercept_errors on;
            proxy_cache STATIC;
            proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 http_404;
            proxy_cache_lock on;
            proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Vary Set-Cookie Expires;
            proxy_hide_header Set-Cookie;
            proxy_cache_valid 200 5m;
            proxy_cache_background_update on;
            proxy_buffering on;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            add_header X-Cached $upstream_cache_status;

            if ($has_os != 1) {
                add_header X-Redirect-Expected true;

                error_page 404 = @downloads-redirect;
                error_page 500 = @downloads-redirect;
                error_page 502 = @downloads-redirect;
                error_page 503 = @downloads-redirect;
                error_page 504 = @downloads-redirect;
            }

            proxy_pass http://foo.bar.com;
        }
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It's my first time configuring an nginx server so there's a good chance I've done something wrong.

Comment: I miss the amount of data to be cached. It looks like it's properly configured but the validity of the cache is just 5 minutes and we don't know how many data is actually required to be cached. If just 20-30 mb of data are to be stored because of few requests or data, it's normal that it doesn't take up much space.

Comment: But shouldn't it remain in cache but be marked as stale? There are frequent content updates so I don't want nginx to hold on for too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much messing about, the key thing I was missing, `inactive=3M;` on the `proxy_cache_path` directive.

`proxy_cache_path /nginx-cache levels=1:2 keys_zone=STATIC:10m max_size=10g use_temp_path=off inactive=3M;`